# Unable to start the server in a digital ocean droplet

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my MERN app to a digital ocean droplet (Ubuntu 20.04 server).

I cloned my GitHub repo to the server.
[image]

Now, when I am trying to start the server using `npm start`, I get the following error.
[image]
The code snippet is as follows:

**server/config/db.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const colors = require("colors");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.bold);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`.red.bold.underline);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
2;
module.exports = connectDB;
```

However, everything works fine on my local machine. If I `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI)`, I get the string.

In the droplet, I tried doing the following:

`export MONGO_URI=the_connection_string`. Even then, I am getting the error.

What am I doing wrong?

ERROR
[image]

Comment: Did you try run npm install after cloning repo?

Comment: Yes, I did npm install after cloning the repo. I am getting the error when I try to run the server using npm start. I am loading the MONGO_URI from the .env file as the first paramater to mongoose.connect( ). This all works fine in my local machine. I dont' know why I am getting the error while in the droplet.

Comment: Cool, Where mongodb is running? How you configure this variable process.env.MONGO_URI?

Comment: I am using MongoDB Atlas. What do you mean when you say how did I configure this variable? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure. According to an image with an error message. mongodb URI is undefined. According to code, you sharing URI received via MONGO_URI env variable. So I guess that this variable is undefined. Try run `export MONGO_URI=[url of your atlas cluster]; npm start`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Should I write the URL inside square brackets? I just wrote `export MONGO_URI = url_of_atlas_cluster`

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the error in the question

Comment: MONGO_URI = url_of_atlas_cluster, replace spaces... This is shell command

Comment: If you the screenshot, there is no space.

Comment: Print variable before executes connect.

Comment: Add `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI)` before `const connectDB = async () => {`.

Comment: Oops, It is undefined. What could be wrong?

Comment: I fixed the issue on my local machine. Console logging `process.env.MONGO_URI` shows the string. Then I pushed the repo to GitHub, cloned the repo to my droplet again (after deleting the previous directory). Then set MONGO_URI as export MONGO_URI=url_of_atlas_cluster. The I ran `npm start`. And I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json

Comment: @HKS is the issue resolved here?

Comment: Yes. The issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had put `.env` inside `.gitignore`. Therefore `.env` was not available in the github repo, which I had cloned to my Digital Ocean droplet. As a solution, I recreated the `.env` file inside my droplet using `vim`. Then I could start the server without any issue.